# Getting a 500 Internal Server Error (require() failed opening required path) on Laravel 5+ Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have installed Laravel many times on Windows OS but never had this problem.

However, on Ubuntu 14.04 I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error, and messages like this in my logs:

> [Wed Jul 22 10:20:19.569063 2015] [:error] [pid 1376] [client 127.0.0.1:52636] PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/laravel_blog/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/laravel_blog/index.php on line 22

Previously I've had problems when mod_rewrite was not installed or set up properly, but I have installed it and it is not working. Changed .htaccess as well from original to this.

```
    +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I've given access to all my folders and files inside i.e.

> /var/www/html/laravel_project

I have all the necessary extensions needed for Laravel 5+ as well. Is there something left that I didn't do?

Comment: Why does it just have `+FollowSymLinks` at the top? Should be `Options +FollowSymLinks`.

Comment: "I have installed rewrite_mod but ..." - and allowed appropriate access for .htaccess with `AllowOverride` in your server config?

Comment: @MikeRockett  i recently removed the "Options" when keeping it the browser goes blank white and when not keeping it the browser returns a 500 request error but in both cases the browser is returning 500 error. !

Comment: @MarcB my error log shows following :-        
[Wed Jul 22 10:20:19.569063 2015] [:error] [pid 1376] [client 127.0.0.1:52636] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/laravel_blog/../bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/laravel_blog/index.php on line 22

Comment: Well, the `Options` must be there - otherwise the file is invalidated. The error says that `www/html/bootstrap/autoload.php` does not exist... So where is the `bootstrap` directory?

Comment: @MikeRockett The directories are all default ... i have not changed any of it. Its inside "laravel_blog/bootstrap/.."

Comment: The `public` and `bootstrap` directories should be under `laravel_blog`, and you should be accessing the app from `laravel_blog/public` - this is the assumption based on the info you've provided thus far. You must have changed something if it is looking for `autoload.php` inside `html/bootstrap/`. Are you using a VirtualHost? If so, is its `DocumentRoot` set to `public`?

Comment: @MikeRockett I've moved my index.php file outside the public and my .htaccess file ..On windows I always did this and accessed my files just doing the localhost/my_site_foler and nevr any errors occured ... But i've been using ubuntu for a week now and here seems to be problem... I think my problem is in .htaccess file but i do not know where it went wrong...

Comment: @MikeRockett .. I've removed the "/../" from the index.php file and tried and showed different errors of file permissions and then chmod and set read/ write permissions and it worked !!! Thanx for the help bro !!

Answer (score 251, accepted):

**Finally Overcame the problem**

- It was not the .htaccess file that was the problem nor the index.php. The problem was on accessing the files and requiring permissions.

For solving the problem i ran the following commands through terminal.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 laravel_blog
```

and then type below to allow laravel to write file to storage folder

```
chmod -R o+w laravel_blog/storage
```

This two commands solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I had this problem when installing laravel onto a fresh ubuntu 14.04 distribution on google compute engine, this solved it.

Comment: this is a very bad advice, the chmod sets all files to +x. I assume you wanted to do it for directories, in which case you'd use find.

Comment: where should I cd (change directory) on in order to execute that command ?

Comment: cd to your /var/www/html directory then execute this command... instead of laravel_blog put your project folder..

Comment: For me on mac terminal I had to put -R before the 755 or it thought -R was the file/folder name. So: sudo chmod -R 755 laravel_project.  The 2nd command was fine. It did fix my problem, so thanks!

Comment: You need many cookies. Worked fine on LAMP Ubuntu 16.04 Installation of Digital Ocean.

Comment: Works on CentOS 7

Comment: for me this work like this `sudo chmod -R 755 laravel_blog`

Comment: these two problems solved my problem partially, but when i run this extra command  `sudo chmod -R o+w laravel_blog/bootstrap` it worked for me.

Comment: You saved me! Thanks so much. Old 5.2 project, updating is done through dragging files in FTP. I feel like I'm in the 90's again

Comment: i agree this totally fubared my dir tree i literally pulled the ethernet cord out immediately...

Comment: should be: find /var/www/docroot/* -type f -exec chmod 660 '{}' \;; find /var/www/docroot/* -type d -exec chmod 770 '{}' \;;find /var/www/docroot/* -type f -exec chmod u+s,g+s '{}' \;;  that is assuming you have a laravel user, if just apache then it could just be 600 and 700

Answer (score 123):

Create the .env file and also run :

```
php artisan key:generate
```

This worked for me after pulling a git project.

After creating .env file and generating the key, run the code below:

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: This worked for me. Don't make a noob mistake, after installing laravel project make sure to rename .env.example to .env or php artisan key:generate will crash

Comment: OK is this a new thing? First time encountering this problem

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear` is working for my case

Comment: can i do these commands with project already in production ?

Comment: What Armin did worked for me as well. If you have a 500 Server Error, just rename the ".env.example" to ".env" and run:

- php artisan key:generate
- php artisan cache:clear
- php artisan config:clear

In my case, I pulled the project to Github repo to local machine. Just make sure you have an updated Composer. Mine's version 8.

Answer (score 34):

Try to check if you have `.env` file.

Mostly this thing can cause something like that. Try to create a file then copy everything from `.env.example`, paste it to your created file and name it `.env`. or jsut simply rename the `.env.example` file to `.env` and run `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: this help in first attempt +

Comment: deploying from live to local/    1-- php artisan key:generate 2-- php artisan config:clear   3-- php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 30):

After installing run below command

```
sudo chmod 755 -R laravel
chmod -R o+w laravel/storage
```

here "laravel" is the name of directory where laravel installed

Comment: with this command make sure to run command `composer install`

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 755 laravel` the location of the -R is wrong

Answer (score 27):

### Make sure a .env file, ***containing an APP_KEY***, exists in root.

What should be in the .env hasn't been explicitly stated in other solutions, and thought I'd boil it down to the sentence above.

This fixed my 500 error on a fresh install of Laravel.

**Steps:**

1. Create a .env file in root (e.g. `touch .env`)
2. Make sure it contains at least one line: `APP_KEY=`
3. Generate an app key in terminal: `php artisan key:generate`

**More .env paramaters:**

As a reference, here's the official .env with useful baseline parameters. Copy-paste what you need:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example

**Notes:**

- My particular installation didn't include any .env whatsoever (example or otherwise)
- Simply having a blank .env does not work.
- A .env containing parameters, but no `APP_KEY` parameter, does not work.

**Bug?:** When generating an app key in terminal, it seems to falsely report success, **however no key will actually get placed in the .env** if the file is missing a line starting with `APP_KEY=`.

Answer (score 14):

I fixed with this Command:

```
   rm -rf app/storage/logs/laravel.logs
   chmod -R 777 app/storage,
   php artisan cache:clear,
   php artisan dump-autoload OR composer dump-autoload
```

Than restart a server eather XAMPP ore another one and that should be working.

Comment: 777 is a very bad command and will give WRITE access to anyone on the internet. 644 is more advisable.

Answer (score 12):

I have faced a similar error. I checked the log in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and found an **UnexpectedValueException**

I changed the owner to my apache user of the storage folder under the project dir.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./storage
```

In my case apache2 process owner is `www-data`, so change this to yours, this can be found in apache2 config file. Hope this is useful to you.

Answer (score 11):

May another solution to this problem:

Install the required packages by running the composer command from the the root of the project:

```
sudo composer install
```

UPDATE:

- You should not run this command on a production server, but some issues with composer can be resolved with this on local envs.

EDIT:

- take a look at https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md to see why running **composer install** as root is not a good idea
- If you need to run it as root, provide the **following flags**, to block third-party code from executing durin the install **--no-plugins --no-scripts**

Comment: What the heck is this , do you actually know what you are answering !

Comment: @JimmyObonyoAbor Actually this is working. According to the logs, the 500 was because some files in /vendor were missing. How do you fix that ? By running composer install/update. Thanks and upvote, Christos Papoulas

Comment: I believe running that command with sudo is a potential security hole

Answer (score 11):

run these commands

```
1. composer install 
2. mv .env.example .env 
3. php artisan cache:clear 
4. composer dump-autoload 
5. php artisan key:generate
```

I had this problem ...

Answer (score 9):

Create `.env` file with the below cmd command:

```
cp .env-example .env
```

Then generate a key for your project:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

After that clear your caches using the below commands:

```
//---Delete Configuration Cahce
php artisan config:cache
//---Clear Application Cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 8):

I read all the comments and suggestions. 500 - HTTP ERROR CODE represents internal server error.

**Reasons for this error:**

- These mainly cause due to permission issues
- Environment variables not found or `.env` file not found on your root directory
- PHP extensions problem
- Database problem

**Fix:**

- Set the correct permissions:

- Run these commands (Ubuntu/Debian)

```
find /path/to/your/root/dir/ -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find /path/to/your/root/dir/ -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/your/root/dir/

chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

- If **.env** file doesn't exist, create one by `touch .env` and paste your environment variables and then run

```
   php artisan key:generate
   php artisan cache:clear
   php artisan config:clear
   composer dump-autoload
```

- Check your php.ini file and uncomment the extensions you need (In some case you have to install the extension by running this command `apt-get install php7.2-[extension-name]`
- Check your database credentials and values in `.env` file. And grant permissions to the database user for that database.

These are some common problem you likely going to face when deploying your laravel app and once you start getting all these commands, I suggest you to make a script which will save your time.

Answer (score 5):

I had PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1 installed and I was using PHP 7.1 on command line and PHP 7.0 was enabled on Apache, that messy can bring problems when you are using Laravel Framework and localhost Apache2 with laravel.

Check your composer file first to see your PHP version.

```
"php": "^7.1.3",
"laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
```

Check your currently php version on command line

```
php -v
```

Check your currently php version enabled on Apache, I did using browser.

```
http://localhost
```

If it's not the same disable the current version and enable the newest one.

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2

sudo a2enmod php7.1

sudo service apache2 restart
```

After that change folder permissions

```
sudo chmod 755 -R blog
```

for storage folder

```
chmod -R o+w blog/storage
```

Answer (score 5):

A frequent issue when using git:

```
Laravel's .gitignore ignores the .env file which when missing generates this error
```

Solved this by manually adding an .env file on the server or uploading it through FTP

Answer (score 5):

First, if there is not `.env` file in your Laravel repository. Copy the `.env.example` file using the following cmd command `cp .env.example .env` and open `.env` file and apply your configuration if needed.

Run these commands:

```
//---Generate Key in your project
php artisan key:generate
//---Flush the application cache
php artisan cache:clear
//---Remove the configuration cache file
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
//---Regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project
composer dump-autoload
//---Restart your Server
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes there is problem with php version. We need to change php version from server. Just write down below string in **.htaccess** file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
```

Answer (score 4):

First allow all permissions for your project folder (let say it's called laravel), for the storage subfolder and its logs subsubfolder and for the vendor subfolder (laravel/storage, laravel/storage/logs and laravel/vendor).

Then check if your have .env file - if not you can run:

```
$ mv .env.example .env
```

to rename your build-in .env.example to the needed .env.

Otherwise turn on the debug mode - open .env and set

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

and open laravel/config/app.php and change

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

to

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

so you can find out what is the reason for your error.

Comment: There's no reason you should be editing config/app.php like that. The would negate the entire purpose of the .env file.

Comment: I was getting Internal Service errors when I ran my laravel app on my test server (in production mode).   Setting APP_DEBUG=true allowed me to see the details of the error, so I could then find and fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Run these two commands in the directory where Laravel is installed:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R DIRECTORY_NAME
chmod -R o+w DIRECTORY_NAME/storage
```

Then clear the cache and dump the auto load:

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this problem many times. Try one of these steps it helped me a lot. Maybe it will also help you.

1. First of all check your file permissions.
2. To fix file permissions **sudo chmod 755 -R your_project**
3. Then **chmod -R o+w your_project/storage** to write file to storage folder.
4. **php artisan cache:clear**
   **composer dump-autoload**
5. **php artisan key:generate**
6. Then **check server requirements** as per the laravel requirement.
7. Many times **you got this** **error because of the php version**. **Try changing your php version** in cpanel.
8. Then configure your  **.htaccess** file properly

Answer (score 3):

If you use vagrant, try this:

First remove config.php in current/vendor.

Run these command:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

NOT RUN php artisan config:cache.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 3):

php artisan require APP_KEY in .env file.
So firstly create .env file in root,

```
sudo nano .env
```

and add APP_KEY= in first line,
save the file and run

```
sudo php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 2):

if its on a live server try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

then also make sure that the php version in your composer.json is the same as that of your server.

Check your php version in your terminal using `php -v`

Answer (score 2):

Check if your .env file is present or not in file structure.
if not, follow the procedures:

1. run command `cp .env.example .env` from projects root directory.
2. run command `php artisan key:generate`
3. refresh the browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Run these two commands on root of laravel

find * -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755 # for directories

find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644 # for files

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with a share Host. I was having 500 error. I just fixed by checking the Laravel version and PHP version. The error was because Laravel 5.6 doesn't run on PHP 7.0.x Once I know this I just reconfigure the project to Laravel 5.5 that is compatible with PHP 7.0.x now everything is right. Another reason I have issues sometimes is the FTP I get corrupted Files and have to upload the project more than once. 
Hope this help in the future I don't found so many information in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who like me still got errors after trying all the other answers :

Check the version of php apache uses, latest laravel only works with php7.1.
So you have to :

```
sudo a2dismod php[yourversion]
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you've run `composer update` on your server instance.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by this commands:

```
mv .env.example .env
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan key:generate
```

then

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs :

```
[06-Feb-2016 22:38:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require(/Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
[06-Feb-2016 22:38:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php') in /Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
[06-Feb-2016 22:43:37 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  require(/Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
[06-Feb-2016 22:43:37 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php') in /Users/tomsihap/Documents/Development/mamp/partie_1_exo/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

There are some failures opening files into the /vendor folder.

By installing and updating via composer, I was able to finally solve the issue.

```
sudo composer install
sudo composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure storage folder with write previlege (chmod o+w), work for me like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Because of no right to write the log's directory.
**chmod 755 storage -R**

Comment: What is different from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35860066/2279200)?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and fixed by upgrade my php version in apache up to 5.6.x

Answer (score 0):

Only change the web folder permission through this command:

`sudo chmod 755 -R your_folder`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following command:

`php artisan passport:install`

I was using passport to run my application completely based on API's and Vue.js. Laravel worked fine but everytime i tried to login via my API i would get the error. After running the command and updating the client_id and client_secret on my Laravel files then pushed the new updates to the live server, the problem was solved. In my user model i have a script as follows:

```
public function generateToken($request)
{
    $http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $http->post(URL::to('/').'/oauth/token', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'password',
            'client_id' => '6',
            'client_secret' => 'x3yhgWVqF8sSaMev4JI3yvsVxfbgkfRJmqzlpiMQ',
            'username' => $this->email,
            'password' => $request->input('password'),
            'scope' => '',
        ],
    ]);
    //  Lets get an array instead of a stdObject so that we can return without errors
    $response = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

    return oq_api_notify([
                'auth' => $response,                                        //  API ACCESS TOKEN
                'user' => $this->load(['settings'])->toArray(),
            ], 201);
}
```

I just updated the client_id and client_secret only then saved. Since the passport command gives you two client keys:

1) Personal access client (client_id & client_secret)

2) Password grant client (client_id & client_secret)

I used the Password grant client. Hopes this helps someone out there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing this issue on the live server then the best way is to add the below-mentioned routes on the web.php file and then run all the routes through URL.

Most of the time this error is because of caches issues and once you clear all the caches - then this error will be solved and you can see to updates codes result.

//Clear Cache facade value:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return '<h1>Cache facade value cleared</h1>';
});
```

//Clear Route cache:

```
Route::get('/route-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:clear');
    return '<h1>Route cache cleared</h1>';
});
```

//Clear View cache:

```
Route::get('/view-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
    return '<h1>View cache cleared</h1>';
});
```

//Clear Config cache:

```
Route::get('/config-clear', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
    return '<h1>Config cleared</h1>';
});
```