# 500 Internal Server Error on local host xampp

Tags: .htaccess, xampp, httpd.conf

I am trying to build an app using Laravel framework.

**Error** The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

I checked httpd.conf to check if mode_rewrite was not commented.I have also tried changing the AllowOverride "None to "All" in httpd.conf file. Can anyone help me please?

The .htaccess file is shown below:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Any errors in the Apache's log?

Comment: /.htaccess: Options not allowed here

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old post, nonetheless I experienced this same issue on OSX and I was able to resolve it with the solution I found [here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04) as follows:

I ran the following commands in terminal.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 laravel_project
```

and then ran the following to give laravel permissions to write to storage folder

```
chmod -R o+w laravel_project/storage
```

NOTE: Before running this in terminal, ensure the xampp welcome page "http://localhost/dashboard" is functional, else it might be something different