# a specific route not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route that is working, but for a specific route, it is not working.

```
Route::get("/index", function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::get("/dynamicrequest1", function () {
    return view('dynamicrequest1');
});
```

the `index` route is working, while the `dynamicrequest1` is not, and by not working, it gives me like this:
[image]

while if i request any other **none exsitence** page, like `bla bla bla`, i get this error

[image]

I have a `dynamicrequest1.blade.php` that contains this simple html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('assets/js/index.js')}}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{URL::asset('assets/css/index.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="./request/send">
        <textarea id="code" contentEditable="true" name="body"></textarea>
        <input type="text" value="http://68.168.100.142:9200/propertywebsites3/_search?size=1" name="endPoint" id="endPoint"/>
        <input type="button" id="formattCode" value="format"/>
        <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Update 1

I am running my project on xampp because when i run it using

> php artisan serve

all the requests return the same error as the `dynamicrequest1` does

#### Update 2

executing

php artisan route:list

giving me:

[image]

Comment: 500 is server error, there gotta be an error somewhere, possibly in your view, try to delete all html and put just one word as a test, and check your logs

Comment: @sef4eg when I put just one word, I get the same error.

Comment: Off the top of my head, to troubleshoot: 1. Try clearing the route cache `artisan route:clear`, 2. In your view remove your URL facades (and possibly the endpoint input you've got there) so you can narrow it down

Comment: Also, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31561357/4018897 permissions always cause me errors...

Comment: @SworrubWehttam the route clear doesn't change anyting, for your second point, I didn't get u, could you repeat in simple english please?

Comment: @SworrubWehttam in the ansewr you've mentioned, I need to execute a terminal command, on which director should I point my terminal to please ?

Comment: What do you get from `artisan route:list`. You need to execute the command from your laravel base directory (the one in which your public directory is)

Comment: You also try to do `Route::get("/dynamicrequest1", function () {
    var_dump('Hello World!')
});` Does that work?

Comment: The fastest and easiest way to find out why you're getting a 500 error is to check the apache logs OR turn on DEBUG in your laravel install which should be in your .ENV , that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Wistar I update my question to give you the route:list

Comment: @Wistar when I put the code your suggest, all pages *including the ones that were working** stop working, when i remove it and put my old route, just the dynamicrequest1 not work

Comment: @odannyc where can I find this .ENV file please ?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent It is hard to tell what it could be from what you have. I would try what Odannyc suggested

Comment: It could be a permission error See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @Wistar * It is hard to tell what it could be from what you have*, Okay tell me what do you want and I execute all the commands that you want and update you by the results

Comment: @Wistar if it is a permission error, why the other route (the index works)?

Comment: It goes back to your Apache logs. WIth xamp I believe they are located there \{Your_xamp_folder}\apache\logs\error.log by default.

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent Okay so youre on XAMPP.. Windows or Mac?

Comment: @odannyc on mac on xampp

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent Click on XAMPP manager > Manage Servers > Apache Web Server > Configure > Open Error Log ....

Comment: okay it is working now, i wrote an answer, it is weird

Comment: @odannyc but though it is working, it is still giving me the old html, when i update the html, it doesn't update, is there a cahs i should delete please ?

Comment: @AnastasieLaurent It's always good to know why things happen and the best place to always look is the logs, so in the future if anything goes wrong look in the logs first and you'll save hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: @odannyc there was nothing in the log, i look before and even now i look but it just says 500 error

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error is an error within your code. I suspect it's your URL::Asset php code. Try to replace the`dynamicrequest1.blade.php` page you have with the one below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="./request/send">
        <textarea id="code" contentEditable="true" name="body"></textarea>
        <input type="text" value="http://68.168.100.142:9200/propertywebsites3/_search?size=1" name="endPoint" id="endPoint"/>
        <input type="button" id="formattCode" value="format"/>
        <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you read the commends, you will see that I already changed this to a simple hello world, and yet I still have the same problem.

Comment: the APP_DEBUG=true is alreayd ther in the.env file

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. I was using Hotspot shield, it was on, when i turn it off, the app works again.

Comment: Could you add details to your answer so your solution could be reproduced

Comment: @Wistar Ok, I was using Hotspot shield, it was on, when i turn it off, the app works again, that is all the details that i have really