# Laravel 5 : deployed on server in public_html give HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, laravel-5, server

I am using laravel 5, I just deployed the code in public_html on the server.
When I call the URL it give me the below error

```
The www.xyz.com page isn’t working

www.xyz.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I think this is not a server issue bcoz when I call the phpinfo file `www.xyz.com/phpinfo.php`, its work.

I start debugging by echo exit, I found that the problem in bootstrap/app.php at 14 line

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

Can anyone suggest me why this happening and how to solve this?
Thanks

Add the cpanel error log

```
File does not exist: /home/kkb/public_html/404.shtml
File does not exist: /home/kkb/public_html/404.shtml, referer: https://www.google.co.in/
File does not exist: /home/kkb/public_html/404.shtml, referer: https://www.google.co.in/
File does not exist: /home/kkb/public_html/404.shtml, referer: http://www.example.com/contact_us.php
File does not exist: /home/kkb/public_html/favicon.ico, referer: http://www.example.com/contact_us.php
File does not exist: /home/kkb/public_html/404.shtml, referer: https://www.google.co.in/
```

My cpanel folder structure for code

[image]

Comment: Did you try with `www.xyz.com/public`?

Comment: check the file and folder permissions. Folder permission should be 0755 and file permission should be 0644.

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud yes i try this, same problem happen

Comment: then @Drudge comments can be solve your problem.Try it.

Comment: @Drudge file and folder permission I checked for bootstrap and aap.php, look same that u suggest.

Comment: @Tarzan whati is the permission of index.php file ?

Comment: 644 on root and  public folder

Comment: You are deploying the laravel application in cpanel right ? If yes then please check the error log which is in cpanel. there you will get error in details.

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: @Drudge i just update my question with latest error log

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: If that don't help add this code in index.php and see the error. Because i don't think the error that you got in log is causing problem.   `try {
    $app->run();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo $e;
    echo "</pre>";
}`

Comment: @Drudge how to give permission, I just update my question with folder structure

Comment: And I try to get error via your code but the same page is shown to me on browser HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Can you ssh in your cpanel ? If yes then check [this ]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt)

Comment: ok, let me try.

Comment: Hi @Drudge via ssh i did like that h-16 [~]# find public_html -type d -exec chod 755 {} \; it give me find: chod: No such file or directory

Comment: i give the permission to folder and file but not working same issue coming