# Deploy laravel project to InfinityFree

Tags: mysql, laravel

I uploaded my Laravel project to infinityfree.net, but get this error:

> This page isn’t working right now sitename.epizy.com can't currently handle this request.
> HTTP ERROR 500

How to fix this?

Comment: `Please note that it can take up to 72 hours for a new domain name to start working everywhere.`, might be the case

Comment: check the error log also, enable debug mode on in Laravel config. Probably there is an issue with the storage directory permission. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543175/getting-a-500-internal-server-error-on-laravel-5-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

You need to "error mood" on in php config file(you can search it in cpanel).error mood off to error mood on to see error log.after you checked the error and solved it change error mood setting.(error mood on to error mood off).I hope this will help you a little.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 500 Internal Server Error is a very general HTTP status code that means something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is.

1. Retry the web page by clicking the refresh/reload button or trying the URL from the address bar again. Even though the 500 Internal Server Error is reporting a general error on the web site's servers and not your computer, the server error may only be temporary. Trying the page again will often be successful.
2. Come back later. The 500 Internal Server Error message is one of the most common error message seen when checking out during an online purchase so sales are often disrupted. This is usually a great incentive to resolve the issue very quickly.
   3.Try Clearing your cache and browser history. It could be possible that the page you are seeing is a cached version, so after the cache is cleared it will go away.
3. You can check the error log button in cPanel under the logs section to see what errors are being given if you have cPanel hosting with us. Sometimes 500 errors can be due to syntax errors in a .htaccess file or other things you may be able to quickly fix yourself.